# Error Execution (4: 8): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

What is  wrong with below query

```
create table financial(
ID int (10) not null,
Segment varchar not null,
Country varchar not null,
Product varchar not null,
Discount_Band varchar (6) not null,
Units_Sold  decimal (10, 2) not null,
Manufacturing_Price decimal (10, 2) not null,
Sale_Price  decimal (10, 2) not null,
Gross_Sales decimal (10, 2) not null,
Discounts decimal (10, 2), 
Sales decimal (10, 2) not null,
COGS decimal (10, 2) not null,
Profit decimal (10, 2) not null,
Dt_Date date,
Month_Number int (2) not null,
Month_Name varchar,
Year int (4) not null,
primary key (ID)
);
```

Comment: The datatypes look to be SQL Server or MySQL dialect; they are not Oracle datatypes. For example, use `INTEGER` instead of `INT(10)` and use `VARCHAR2(100)` (or whatever the size) instead of `VARCHAR`. Note the `2` in `VARCHAR2`--that's an Oracle thing.

Comment: Thanks it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE financial(
  2    id                   INT NOT NULL,
  3    segment              VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL,
  4    country              VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL,
  5    product              VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL,
  6    discount_band        VARCHAR2(6)NOT NULL,
  7    units_sold           DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
  8    manufacturing_price  DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
  9    sale_price           DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
 10    gross_sales          DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
 11    discounts            DECIMAL(10,2),
 12    sales                DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
 13    cogs                 DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
 14    profit               DECIMAL(10,2)NOT NULL,
 15    dt_date              DATE,
 16    month_number         INT NOT NULL,
 17    month_name           VARCHAR2(10),
 18    year                 INT NOT NULL,
 19    PRIMARY KEY(id)
 20  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

So, what was wrong with your code?

- `INT` doesn't have size
- don't use `VARCHAR` but `VARCHAR2` datatype; that's not an *error* but recommendation
- `VARCHAR2` must have a size
- you don't have to specify the `NOT NULL` constraint for the `ID` column as you set it to be a primary key; primary keys don't allow nulls anyway. Also not an error, just saying

Comment: Thank you very much.